# OpenShift oc new-app IMAGE versus oc new-app --docker-image

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin

The syntax for creating a new application on OpenShift based on a Docker image is a little confusing:

```
Usage:
  oc new-app (IMAGE | IMAGESTREAM | TEMPLATE | PATH | URL ...) [options]
. . .
Options:
  . . . 
  --docker-image=[]: Name of a Docker image to include in the app.
  . . .
```

What is the difference between specifying a docker image as the `IMAGE` argument and indicating the image in the `--docker-image` option?

Let's say my image is in docker hub (docker.io) and it is `myid/myrepo:latest`. Is the command below the correct way to create the application?

```
oc new-app myid/myrepo:latest --docker-image="docker.io/myid/myrepo:latest"
```

I'm using OpenShift v1.3.0.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because `oc new-app` overloads on the argument in:

```
(IMAGE | IMAGESTREAM | TEMPLATE | PATH | URL ...)
```

it can sometimes because of precedence order in the algorithm not choose the match you are after. The `--image` option allows you to be explicit about what you want and bypass `oc new-app` trying to infer what you wanted. You do not need to supply both, so either of these should usually work:

```
oc new-app myid/myrepo:latest
oc new-app --image myid/myrepo:latest
```

If the image is on Docker Hub Registry, you should be able to drop the `docker.io` as will search there by default. The hostname part for the registry should only be needed when using an alternate registry.